# The Stacks project

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, textbook-recommendation, online-resources

I have a question concerning the admirable [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/).

> Which comparable projects are there:
>
> - **approach-wise**: "an open source textbook on algebraic stacks and the algebraic geometry that is needed to define them", i.e. projects
>   as "an open source textbook on X and the Y that is needed to define
>   (and understand) X"
> - **technical-wise** <sub>[Side question: which technical framework(s) is the Stacks Project based on?]</sub>
> - **tag-system-wise** (using the same [tag system](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags) as the Stacks Project)
> - **tag-wise** (with a significant number of [tags](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/blob/master/tags/tags) shared with the Stacks Project)?

The question concerns also the possible interoperability of several such projects.

Comment: This looks like a question for Meta to me.

Comment: https://gerby-project.github.io

Comment: I am not sure if this question is on topic here..

Answer (score 8):

**tag-system-wise** Anyone can use [Gerby](https://gerby-project.github.io), with a similar tag system. The actual tag assignment isn't dealt with by Gerby, you can set up your own conventions if you like. There might be some minor things you'll have to change if you decide to do so.

So far I'm not aware of anyone actually doing this, except for the work-in-progress [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net), which will be Gerby applied to the works of Jacob Lurie. There's no fixed date to go live yet, maybe in September we'll have a more definite idea about this.

Observe that the text will *not* be open-source (there's no need for this in the Gerby system).

**tag-wise** No projects share tags with the Stacks project (as there are no other projects using a similar tag system), although it is often cited. It's also not quite desirable to "share" tags, as nothing ensures uniqueness of tags then.

**technical-wise** This has been answered before, but feel free to ask follow-up questions (which probably would be better done via e-mail, or chat), as I'm the person responsible for the majority of the implementation (with help from @RaymondCheng).

Answer (score 3):

**approach-wise:**

Open source text books on a variety of topic in mathematics (and other sciences), mainly [CC BY licensed](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/), so the content can be freely shared and adapted, even for commercial use:

- [OpenStax](https://cnx.org)
- [College Open](http://www.collegeopentextbooks.org/mathematics-textbooks/) (some with a non-commercial-use restriction)
- [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Subject:Pure_mathematics)

<sub>Answer to side question: Stacks is based on a LaTeX processing tool built using [plastex](https://github.com/tiarno/plastex) and
a website built using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (see [Gerby](https://gerby-project.github.io)).</sub>